# not able to read jar files when doing maven build

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-tool-suite

I have imported maven project and its dependent jars on **spring tool suite** now I am doing **maven build** it is showing 100 errors all are regarding jar files but all jar files are present in my work space and there is no red mark on project explorer.

package javax.validation.constraints does not exist

package org.hibernate.validator.constraints does not exist

Comment: What does this means: "present in my workspace" ?

Comment: Sometimes the local JAR files in the Maven cache are corrupt. In such cases, I always recommend to wipe out the local Maven repo cache (usually located in ~/.m2/repository) and do a "Maven -> Update Project" afterwards in Eclipse/STS. This triggers Maven to download the JAR files again.

Comment: Solved- Actually at runtime it is not able to find the jar classes. SO i write a code into pom.xml for adding dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the jars are blocked. Unblock them and try .

Many time i encountered this error with the new jars which i import to a workspace and the error comes as jar not found .

Comment: How to check jars are blocked or not? Can you please tell me?